# I've tried writing a python code for finding a factorial using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

Program to find factorial of a number using recursion

```
def fact(n) :

    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else :
        print ("The factorial of given number is {0}".format(n*fact(n-1)))

n = int(input("enter the number : "))
fact(n)
```

But it's showing the following error which i'm unable to rectify

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
  File "python", line 7, in fact
  File "python", line 7, in fact
  File "python", line 7, in fact
  File "python", line 7, in fact
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: `fact` returns None is `n` is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: All paths should return a value.  Here the else path returns `None`. You generally should not print in the function unless it's for debugging purposes.  The function has one job, not  two.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this question: what is my function doing when it is called with argument `n-1` (assume `n-1 >= 1`).

It returns nothing. Therefore `n*fact(n-1)` means - multiply `n` by nothing.

Probably, you want to see this result:

```
def fact(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        temp = n * fact(n - 1)
        print('The factorial of ', n, ' is ', temp)
        return temp
```

fact(5)
The factorial of  1  is  1
The factorial of  2  is  2
The factorial of  3  is  6
The factorial of  4  is  24
The factorial of  5  is  120
120

Answer (score 1):

As @alexanderfridman says, you are not returning a value for numbers greater than 1, so the results are not going to happen.  Trivial solution might read:

```
def fact(n=1):
    if n <= 1: return 1
    return n * fact(n-1)
```